# Returning items which are not listed twice in the database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

With the following data, how do I identify only those rows which don't have an entry for their `taskid` with a `1` *AND* `2` in the status column? (Row 7/8)

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
        ([id] bigint, [taskid] uniqueidentifier, [status] int)
    ;

    INSERT INTO TestTable
        ([id], [taskid], [status])
    VALUES
        (1, '7AF6F773-7B55-4B51-9742-00C829641C8D', 1),
        (2, '7AF6F773-7B55-4B51-9742-00C829641C8D', 2),
        (3, '21DA1039-9EA1-42BE-A2BC-02AC46D6A34B', 1),
        (4, '21DA1039-9EA1-42BE-A2BC-02AC46D6A34B', 2),
        (5, '5FC0BCEA-A097-466B-A1F8-120A57584406', 1),
        (6, '5FC0BCEA-A097-466B-A1F8-120A57584406', 2),
        (7, '14227447-E42F-41A1-8431-1C6465814455', 1),
        (8, '66383B5F-3795-4E4B-85C9-223EA5B3D007', 2)
    ;
```

I have tried this query but it returns all rows

```
select [id],[taskid], [status] 
from testtable
group by status, taskid, id
  having count(taskid) < 2
 order by taskid
```

Not sure how else to approach it? Is it a case for a subquery/CTE? If so, how would that work? I thought this would be reasonably simple to achieve.

My expected output is

```
7, '14227447-E42F-41A1-8431-1C6465814455', 1
8, '66383B5F-3795-4E4B-85C9-223EA5B3D007', 2
```

I expect these rows back because they are the only two which do not have an entry for 1 and 2. Therefore the `count` of the `taskId` should be 1.

SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4acb9/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach, using `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY taskid) cnt
    FROM testtable
)

SELECT id, taskid, status
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 1
```

The idea here is to first make a pass over your table and generate a count for each group of records belonging to the same `taskid`.  Then, subquery that CTE and restrict to only tasks which appeared once.

Comment: If a taskid came with a status more than 1 time this solution doesn't work fine

Comment: @masoud If this be a concern, then the OP would have to update his question, because it is not even clear how my answer would need to be modified.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved that problem with a subquery for not repeated lines.

```
SELECT id, taskid, status
from testtable
where taskId IN (
 SELECT distinct taskid
 from TestTable
 group by taskid
 having count(taskid) < 2)
```

The reason to do it like this is that you only need to group it by `taskid`, and it´s impossible to recover it without another query or join into it.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
select * 
from TestTable 
where taskid not in (
                   select taskid 
                   from TestTable 
                   where status=1 and taskid in 
                                 (select taskid 
                                  from TestTable 
                                  where status=2))
```

this is not the best solution but helps you